# Angular 6 Passing Query Param to Root

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

In my `app.routing.module.ts` I have the following routes configured:

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
  path: '',
  component: AdminLayoutComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }]
}
```

I want to pass an optional query parameter to the root of the app, which in my case is `DashboardComponent`.

In my `AdminModule` I'm configuring my routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: '/:id', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];
```

I can't seem to access that id param if I do this in my Dashboard Component:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
  params => console.log(params) // I get nothing here
);
```

An ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I was able to do it:

Simply navigate like this:

```
<span class="cursor-pointer" [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{ 'id': 82860}">Edit</span>
```

And in `Root Component` get it like this:

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id')
```

We don't need to define a route for query params. It will appear in your url like this: `http://localhost:4200/?id=82860`.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation illustrates very well how to share parameters within a route:

HTML Template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]">
  <span class="badge">{{ hero.id }}</span>{{ hero.name }}
</a>
```

Or in component:

```
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
}
```

Component:

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;

  private selectedId: number;

  constructor(
    private service: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
        return this.service.getHeroes();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score -1):

So u dont need to define route with no params:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '/:id', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];
```

And in your component just check if id is null:

```
this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    if(params['id'] == null) {
        // do what u need
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. `this.router.navigate(['/'], {queryParams: {id: plna_no}});`, I'm using this to navigate to dashboard. But I get nothing in params.